# Force Thunderbird to open ALL links in Chrome?

Tags: 15.04, thunderbird

I have set Chrome as default Internet browser. But Thunderbird still chooses to open some links in Chrome and some in Firefox.

Can I force Thunderbird to open all links in Chrome only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the step to set Default Browser for all Thunderbird mail links

1. Go to Thunderbird Menu:  Edit-->Preferences
2. Click Config Editor
3. Click on "I 'll be careful, I promise'
4. Then in next screen search below entries one by one,

   - network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http
   - network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https
   - network.protocol-handler.warn-external.ftp
5. If the value column is false then make it true, you can change value of entry using double click on the row.

Comment: Hm it still opens some http links in Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: This method stop working for me too, at least in version 52.5.0. Then I found a way going into the "Attachments" tab in "Peferences" menu and searching for "http" and "https", then changing values to the browser I want or to "Allways ask".

Answer (score 0):

The method described by Vipul Bhatt stop working for me, at least in Thunderbird version 52.5.0 (Ubuntu 16.04). I found a way going into the "Attachments" tab in "Peferences" menu and searching for "http" and "https", and then changing values to the browser I want or to "Allways ask". Problem solved.

Comment: Still seems to force firefox.